# Creating a Scrollable XYChart - Running into cut-off problems

Tags: java, charts, javafx

I am trying to make an XYChart that is scrollable (actually pannable, but since ScrollPane offers a `setPannable(boolean pannable)` function, they are really equivalent). The type of XYChart I am using is a candle-stick chart, that is essentially identical to the code released by rterp @ Github which is available here:

[StockChartsFX](https://github.com/rterp/StockChartsFX)

Which is itself seemingly derived mostly from Ensemble8, I discovered.

As it was originally setup:

CandleStickChart extends XYChart extends Chart

but then I realized that XYChart does not expose enough data to be able to really mess around with how the chart functions, so I created a ScrollableXYChart class and, since I had already gone that far, decided to create a MultiChart class as well just in case I needed to go up to that level (it is not only scrolling that I am implementing, I am also implementing toolbars and other such things, but do not need assistance with that at the moment). ScrollableXYChart and MultiChart were just copy-pasted from XYChart and Chart respectively (from Java 8u40 ea 23).

In order to make the chart content scrollable, I did the following:

```
private ScrollPane plotAreaScrollPane = new ScrollPane();

public ScrollableXYChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis)
{
    ...
    plotAreaScrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    plotAreaScrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    plotAreaScrollPane.setPannable(true);
    plotAreaScrollPane.setPrefSize(800, 600);
    plotAreaScrollPane.setContent(plotArea);
    getChartChildren().addAll(plotBackground, plotAreaScrollPane, xAxis, yAxis);
    ...
}
```

After doing that the chart content was inside a ScrollPane and the width looked correctly scaled to the chart, the only problem is that, when scrolling to the right, **candles are not rendered**. I noticed that resizing the window of the application will force more candles to be drawn, so I thought that maybe if I set the width inside of `layoutChartChildren(...)` that would force more candles to be drawn. It does appear to do that, but doing so makes the ScrollPane unscrollable (the horizontal thumb of the scrollbar becomes the full width of the bar).

After looking into the `layoutPlotChildren(...)` method of the CandleStickChart I realized that it was iterating over the data like so:

```
Iterator<Data<String, Number>> iter = getDisplayedDataIterator(series);
while (iter.hasNext())
{
    // draw candle
}
```

So just in case that was cutting off the number of candles drawn, I replaced it with:

```
int candleIndex = 0;

for (Data<String, Number> datum: getData().get(seriesIndex).getData())
{
    // draw candle
}
```

But that did not change anything.

Here are some screenshots (and yes there is more data than is being shown.. I tried with 5000+ candles) to be sure:

[image: Candles are shown]
[image: No candles when scrolled]

Thanks very much.

**Update:**

After some more thought and research, I changed the CandleStickChart from an `XYChart<String, Number>` to an `XYChart<Number, Number>` Doing so allowed me to set the bounds of the x-axis, via `setLowerBound(...)` and `setUpperBound(...)` methods in `ValueAxis<Number>`. With access to these new methods, I atttempted to add the following change listener on the `hvalueProperty` of the ScrollPane:

```
private double lastHoffset = 0d;
```

...

```
plotAreaScrollPane.hvalueProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    double hmin = plotAreaScrollPane.getHmin();
    double hmax = plotAreaScrollPane.getHmax();
    double hvalue = plotAreaScrollPane.getHvalue();
    double contentWidth = plotAreaScrollPane.getContent().getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
    double viewportWidth = plotAreaScrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth();
    double hoffset = Math.max(0, contentWidth - viewportWidth) * (hvalue - hmin) / (hmax - hmin);

    double dHoffset = hoffset - lastHoffset;
    lastHoffset = hoffset;
    xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    xAxis.setAnimated(false);
    getXAxis().setLowerBound(getxAxis().getLowerBound() + hoffset);
    getXAxis().setUpperBound(getxAxis().getUpperBound() + hoffset);
});
```

Hopeful, I tried seeing what happened. However, no (visible) change.

**Update:**
I was able to get it working by tinkering with almost every possible setting...I still am not quite sure what combination of settings made it work, but it involved commenting out `plotArea.setClip(plotAreaClip);` and setting:

```
    plotArea.setAutoSizeChildren(false);
    plotContent.setAutoSizeChildren(false);
```

to:

```
    plotArea.setAutoSizeChildren(true);
    plotContent.setAutoSizeChildren(true);
```

and

```
    plotContent.setManaged(false);
    plotArea.setManaged(false);
```

to:

```
    plotContent.setManaged(true);
    plotArea.setManaged(true);
```

Somehow this makes it work. Someone much smarter than I am could probably explain why, and which settings are actually truly necessary, and what are the (potentially negative) implications of changing these settings, as I am sure the author put them there for good reasons.